# C# Console Opacity/Transparency

Tags: c#, console, transparency, opacity

Is there a way to change the Console's opacity to make it semi-transparent?
Also is there a way to change the console's background color to a custom color?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://johnhasson.com/index.php/transparent-and-glass-console-in-c/) example, should be what you want to do.

Comment: Yes I have seen that post but the problem is the entire window would be transparent - making the text impossible to read. What I really was looking for was just making the background transparent, not the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

a quick google revealed [this site](http://johnhasson.com/index.php/transparent-and-glass-console-in-c/) which has a the code for a console app that has a transparent  window.

essnetially, you have to get the handle to the console window and call some native API methods, chiefly `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey,byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
```

Comment: Yes I have seen that post but the problem is the entire window would be transparent - making the text impossible to read. What I really was looking for was just making the background transparent, not the whole window.

Comment: No, the native console window does not support that. You'll need to switch to a different console application or Mac OS X. @chr

Comment: it does not support it "nativly" however, you can get around this if you jump through the right hoops.  I tried the code from that link myself. it works just fine--but it affects the whole window, which is NOT what the OP wants.